# How does $x^2+y^2+z^2>2z$ look like on a 3D plane?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

This would be a highlighted region of a sphere centred at the origin where it satisfies the condition greater than $2z$?

I can't seem to visualise this. Any help would be appreciated. Tried on geogebra and it didn't work.

Comment: I think it may be $x^2+y^2+z^2>2z$...

Comment: Bring the the $2z$ term to the left hand side and complete the square. You will get the complement of a sphere that is not centered at the origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x^2 + y^2 + (z-1)^2 > 1$ is all the points outside of a sphere of radius $1$ centred at $(0,0,1).$ (assuming the question meant: $x^2+y^2+z^2>2z$ )

Answer (score 0):

As @Adam Rubinson said (assuming the question meant: $x^2+y^2+z^2 >2z$): [image]

Comment: Your drawing should be of all points outside of the sphere.

Comment: @JohnDouma : yes, as Adam Rubinson wrote; a little imagination will easily exploit this geogebra illustration.

Comment: @JohnDouma it is difficult to draw/illustrate all the points outside of a sphere...

Comment: @AdamRubinson Isn't there a way to invert the colors? Perhaps the sphere can be made white and the gray of the plane can be extended to three dimensional space. As it stands, the drawing looks like the sphere, not its complement.

Comment: No idea if inverting the colours would help but maybe you're right...